# Question about at __strcmp_sse42 (vg_replace_strmem.c:852) In C

Tags: c

May I have a question about my error during valgrind check?

I don't know how to fix this error below:
at 0x4C2E2B1: __strcmp_sse42 (vg_replace_strmem.c:852)

Comment: Maybe `argv[1]` is NULL?

Comment: You should always check `argc` to make sure that the expected arguments were passed.

Comment: Assuming that you didn't lie to us, there is only one strcmp there and so argv[1] must be corrupt. It is either NULL or pointing to some random location. Debug and find out which it is. It is most likely that you didn't check argc before trying to use argv[1].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs when the string doesn't a `NULL` terminated string. In this case, the value `"-all"` or `argv[1]` maybe doesn't a `NULL` terminated string, therefore the `strlen` will return an indeterminate value, because `strcmp` goes past the end of the strings and past the memory you allocated for them.
Try add `\0` in the end of the string before the `strcmp`.

Comment: `NULL` is a null pointer, it's not the null terminator of a string, which is `'\0'`

Comment: If `argv` is the standard parameter to `main()`, it's guaranteed to be null terminated. It's more likely that the problem is that there's no `argv[1]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It works!